# Data load long time from server

Tags: angularjs, rest, request

Hello I'm have REST for get data from server(after click button). But this request complete after long time about 3-5 minutes. For user I'm want show progress bar or other notify, what solution you use for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know how long it will take, the easiest solution is to display an animated gif.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this [Angular Loading Bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/). Read documentation first.